# installing subversion (and C libraries in general) in windows 7

Tags: c++, c, svn, gcc, gnu

I am trying to install Subversion on my computer. I have a source code I am supposed to compile, just like a C library, which I find tricky because I am not used to it.

In the folder, there are, among other files:
configure.ac
Makefile.in

In the readme, it says I have to use the standard GNU procedure to compile:

```
      $ ./configure
      $ make
      # make install
```

But when writing gcc ./configure.ac in the command line, it says

```
C:\Users\SC5\Downloads\subversion-1.8.9\subversion-1.8.9>gcc configure.ac
c:/strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-m
ingw32/bin/ld.exe:configure.ac: file format not recognized; treating as linker s
cript
c:/strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-m
ingw32/bin/ld.exe:configure.ac:1: syntax error
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea? A general path on how to install with .config files in general?

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: I would just install TortoiseSVN. And select the command line tools when installing. http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

Comment: Why are you executing `gcc configure.ac`

Comment: @drescherjm I thought that's how you do? But please, tell me how you normally do, that's what I am looking for here :)

Comment: On linux using gcc (I do not use gcc directly on windows) the normal procedure for most software compiled with gcc is configure then make then make install just like in your example. You are saying that there is no configure script but only a configure.ac. I believe you can generate a configure script using autotools but I can't help with that.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows, just download the .exe and hit enter on it.

Comment: I would like everything to be that simple :) Now, just in case this was not possible (if there is no .exe or .msi), would you be able to solve the case above?